# Read ID and statusnodes of xml

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe3

I have a problem with reading some xml nodes with Delphi.
I want to read the id from this xml code

example:

```
<row name="String.101" status="new" comment="">
      <native>&quot;User Name&quot;</native>
      <lang id="en" status="ready">&quot;User Name&quot;</lang>
      <lang id="fr" status="translated">&quot;Nom d&apos;utilisateur&quot;</lang>
      <lang id="hu" status="translated">&quot;Felhasználó neve&quot;</lang>
      <lang id="it" status="translated">&quot;Nome utente&quot;</lang>
      <lang id="zh" status="translated">&quot;用户名&quot;</lang>
      <lang id="de" status="ready">&quot;Benutzername&quot;</lang>
    </row>
```

My program should show me the 'en' in "id="en"' but it shows me "User Name" at the end of the line.

Where are my errors in my delphi code?

```
begin
      TransNodes  := XMLDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['targets'].ChildNodes['target'].ChildNodes['stringdata'].ChildNodes;

      for i := 0 to TransNodes.Count -1 do
      begin
        sContext        := TransNodes[i].Attributes['name'];
        sOriginalStatus := TransNodes[i].Attributes['status'];
        sNativeText     := TransNodes[i].ChildNodes['native'].Text;
        sLangId         := TransNodes[i].ChildNodes['id'].Text;
        sStatus         := TransNodes[i].ChildNodes['status'].Text;
        Delete(sNativeText, Length(sNativeText), 1);
        Delete(sNativeText, 1, 1);
        Delete(sLangId, Length(sLangId), 1);
        Delete(sLangId, 1, 1);
        Delete(sStatus, Length(sStatus), 1);
        Delete(sStatus, 1, 1);


       Memo.Lines.Add(sContext + ' ' + sOriginalStatus + ' ' + sNativeText + ' ' + sLangId + ' ' + sStatus);
```

i tried it with .Attributes and with .ChildNodes... with .Attributes delphi shwos me an error.
The same problem with status. i want, for example, 'status="ready"' but he shows me nothing.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: sorry, the first link is wrong!
This is the right one ;)
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zoyudjkn4oevtt4/LbHmzPfdpU/Share/2013/10#lh:null-xml%20code.png

Comment: have you tried to comment out the Delete(... lines of code, might be you just delete your result?

Comment: I tried it, but nothing happend. It wont show me the message i need.

Comment: anyway it would be much easier to review your problem if you paste relevant code (xml and delphi) in your question. code is shown formatted if you put 4 whitespaces before each line

Comment: this should be better for you

Comment: Better but we still have to guess that your 'row' node is a sub-node of 'stringdata'. The more obvious you present your problem the better we can help. It might be trivial for this question but being more detailed might help you in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to access id and status as nodes but those are attributes of the 'lang' node

try the following (not tested but it should access the first 'lang' node... it should be wrapped in another for loop since you have more then one 'lang' node)

```
sLangId := TransNodes[i].ChildNodes['lang'].firstChild.Attributes['id'];
sStatus := TransNodes[i].ChildNodes['lang'].firstChild.Attributes['status'];
```